# How to place folder/jar in Maven META-INF root

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sap-cloud-platform

I am working on a implementation that requires UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8 for SAP hana cloud platform. The documentation tells me that i need to place it under the following structure:

WAR file:
META-inf
 - ext_security
   - jre8

The problem is when i include the jars it goes to WEB-INF/classes and thats not where the server is looking. As seen in the picture.

[image: Root META-INF]

Technical details:

tomcat 8: v3.2 runtime
JRE 1.8
Maven build: using webapp archatype
With facades to support servlets.
IDE: eclipse

Tried the following:

1. add files using eclipse web deployment assembly (for what ever the reason it does not seems to work with maven and yes i use .m2 and WTP plugin)
2. Adding files trough maven dependency and tried copy to output folder.
3. i open WAR file moved files manually to correct folder and re-zipped and verified that if its in correct folder the update to server is working fine.

i really hope you can help me.

kind regards,

UPDATE: as requested by khmarbaise the pom file. And i created web-inf folder by myself in the hope it would be placed in root.

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>hcp</groupId>
  <artifactId>edi.web</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>edi.web Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>



  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- tried classpath but it did not seem to do annything 
 Below dependency is from local .m2 repository-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>hcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jre8security</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
      <!-- goes in manifest classpath, but not included in WEB-INF/lib -->
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>


        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

  </build>
</project>
```

**Solution provided by pace:**

create a source folder under the following name: src/main/webapp/META-INF

Comment: Can you show your full pom file cause what you are wishing will be done by default ? Cause if you get the `META-INF` in `WEB-INF` than there is something wrong...

Comment: pom id added. but i added meta-inf by hand in source folder in the hope it would still pick up,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maven-war-plugin's war goal has a configuration option [webappDirectory](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#webappDirectory).  It defaults to src/main/webapp.  Anything in there will be placed in the root of the war.  So you could create a directory:

```
src/main/webapp/META-INF
```

and drop in whatever files you want there.  I don't much about the web tools plugin so not sure what approach would work there.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you so very mush. i was trying to d this trough dependency but this is so mush easier.